# Limit number of connections to instances with AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We are using AWS classic ELB for our service and our service can only serve x number of requests at a time. If the number of requests are greater than x then we do not want to route those requests to the instance and neither do we want to lose those requests. We would like to limit the number of connections to the instances registered with the ELB. Is there some ELB setting to configure max connections to instances?

Another solution I could find was to use ELB connection draining but based on the ELB doc **[1]** , using connection draining will mark the instance as OutofService after serving in-flight requests. Does that mean the instance will be terminated and de-registered from ELB after in-flight requests are served? We do not want to terminate and de-register the instances, we just want to limit the number of connections to the instances. Any solutions?

**[1**] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-conn-drain.html

Comment: You don't want to send the excess requests to an instance and you do not want to lose the requests. What did you want to do with them? Also, can you provide more information about your back-end -- do requests take a long time (eg 20+ seconds) or are they very quick requests? Are the requests coming from web browsers or from back-end systems (eg an API call)?

Comment: @John's question, *"What did you want to do with them?"* is crucial.  They need to go somewhere, or result in an immediate error, or they need to be enqueued at the balancer until either an available slot to a back-end is available or a timeout expires after waiting too long for a timeslot.  ELB can't do this, but it can be done with HAProxy, which can be deployed behind ELB for redundancy.  I do this in sone of my applications -- suspending overflow requests until a timeslot to a backend is free.  Please clarify your intended action for the overflow requests.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  The requests would be coming from API calls . Requests do not take a very long time (<20 seconds) and we do not want to result in an immediate error, instead we would like to enqueue it at ELB so they can be routed to the instance when instance is able to serve the request

Comment: Why not have them drop messages onto a SQS queue? Then you can control the rate at which you ingest messages and let requests come in as fast at they are sent, you would need some way to send the message back to the requester or scale the app instances like Chris White suggested in his answer.

Comment: Going with the original title, is there a way to tell the ELB "each of my 3 instances can only handle up to 150 concurrent; if you get more than 450 concurrent, give me 450 and **drop the rest**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ELB is more meant to spread traffic evenly across instances registered for it. If you have more traffic, you throw up more instances to deal with it. This is generally why a [load balancer is matched with an auto scaling group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/autoscaling-load-balancer.html). The Auto Scaling Group will look at set constraints and based on that either spins up more instances or pulls them down (ie. your traffic starts to slow down).

Connection draining is more meant for pulling traffic from bad instances so it doesn't get lost. Bad instances mean they aren't passing health checks because something on the instance is broken. ELB by itself doesn't terminate instances, that's another part of what the Auto Scaling Group is meant to do (basically terminate the bad instance and spin up a new instance to replace it). All ELB does is stop sending traffic to it.

Answer (score 3):

It appears your situation is:

- Users are sending API requests to your Load Balancer
- You have several instances associated with your Load Balancer to process those requests
- You do not appear to be using Auto Scaling
- You do not always have sufficient capacity to respond to incoming requests, but you do not want to lose any of the requests

In situations where requests come at a higher rate than you can process them, you basically have three choices:

1. You could put the messages into a **queue** and consume them when capacity is available. You could either put *everything* in a queue (simple), or only use a queue when things are too busy (more complex).
2. You could **scale to handle the load**, either by using **Auto Scaling** to add additional Amazon EC2 instances or by using **AWS Lambda** to process the requests (Lambda automatically scales).
3. You could **drop requests** that you are unable to process. Unless you have implemented a queue, this is going to happen at some point if requests rise above your capacity to process them.

The best solution is to use **AWS Lambda functions** rather than requiring Amazon EC2 instances. Lambda can tie directly to **AWS API Gateway**, which can front-end the API requests and provide security, throttling and caching.

The simplest method is to use **Auto Scaling** to increase the number of instances to try to handle the volume of requests you have arriving. This is best when there are predictable usage patterns, such as high loads during the day and less load at night. It is less useful when spikes occur in short, unpredictable periods.

To fully guarantee no loss of requests, you would need to use a **queue**. Rather than requests going directly to your application, you would need an initial layer that receives the request and pushes it into a queue. A backend process would then process the message and return a result that is *somehow* passed back as a response. (It's more difficult providing responses to messages passed via a queue because there is a disconnect between the request and the response.)

Answer (score 0):

AWS ELB is practically no limit to get request. If your application handle only 'N' connection, Please go with multiple servers  behind the ELB and set ELB  health check URL will be your application URL. Once your application not able to respond the request, ELB automatically forward your request to another server which is behind ELB. So that you are not going to miss any request.